# Pulse Shaping Inquiry

Tags: communication, digital-communications

I am really confused about how several books and videos handle Pulse Shaping.In order to avoid ISI (Inter Symbol Interference: Energy from one sample leaking into the energy of the other, creating uncertainties)  and have finite bandwidth, Nyquist suggested using a Sinc impulse response.

Every System (not recorded) is Causal in nature. Overhere the impulse comes later while the output starts producing the Sinc impulse response so its peak comes ontop of the sample point. Also somehow the future impulses tend to affect current values.

[image]

Can someone explain me how is this possible?

Comment: Please define ISI

Comment: Inter Symbol Interference. Energy from one sample leaks into the energy of the other. This creates uncertainties

Comment: Please only use comments for comments adding detail or clarification to your question should be in question body. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Peter Halpern implemented Sin(x)/x filters using trigonometric pulse forming networks, to create signaling methods that looked like noise, used I suspect for covert communications.

Comment: An *ideal* SINC filter is non-causal.

Answer (score 0):

Some filters (e.g., digital FIR filters) introduce a delay that gives them a limited ability to "peer into the future" and produce a good approximation to the ideal sinc response.

Comment: ie. you don't actually "look into the future", you just delay the presence long enough

Comment: @Marcus Müller: I guess that's why there are quotes

Answer (score 0):

There is group delay in all filters which may cause ISI.  The next pulse affects the present pulse in less time than overall group delay so it is not realy in the future but due to spectral components with lower group delay.

"raised cosine filters" are best for harmonic pulses 1T, 2T etc since ringing occurs at T for minimal ISI.  Pulse position modulation requires Elliptic or maximally flat group delay.

Sinc response is used for video to reduce ghosting from overshoot, but for data, some overshoot with center sampling and zero ISI on edges is OK.